# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on FileOutputStream.write

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm using the following codes to download an image from an URL and save it to sd card. Although the image is downloaded well, the app crashes out. Where is the problem?

```
val picUrl = URL("http://example.com/")
val urlConnection = picUrl.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
urlConnection.requestMethod = "GET"
urlConnection.doOutput = true
urlConnection.connect()
val path = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/myFolder")
if (!path.exists()){
    path.mkdirs()
}
val file = File(path,((Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()).toString() + ".jpg"))
file.createNewFile()
val fileOutput = FileOutputStream(file)
val inputStream = urlConnection.inputStream
val totalSize = urlConnection.contentLength
var downloadedSize = 0
val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
var bufferLength: Int
do {
      bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)
      if (bufferLength == 0)
            break
      fileOutput.write(buffer,0,bufferLength)
      downloadedSize += bufferLength
    }
         while (true)
fileOutput.close()
if (totalSize == downloadedSize){
   //the image has been downloaded 
   //do sth with downloaded image
}
```

**The error in logcat:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1024; regionStart=0; regionLength=-1
    at java.util.Arrays.checkOffsetAndCount(Arrays.java:1719)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:487)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:186)
```

Comment: If the file downloads fine then you should post the code that executes after the download

Comment: @mTak   Logcat is clearly saying that the problem is due to FileOutputStream.write. Anyway, I'm just storing `file.absolutePath` in SQLite db.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `if (bufferLength == 0)`  
to `if (bufferLength == -1)`  
-1 is returned when there is no more data